# Dom Exception 18 in javascript/html5 when trying to access local storage

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios7

I have the following html that tries to set one key in local storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
  function loaded(){
    try {
      window.localStorage.setItem("Test", "SetItemValue");
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Test OK";
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Test FAIL<br>" + err.message;
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">Testing...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On one single iPhone5 this causes the following exception.

> Test FAIL
>  SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Other iPhones tested (three others) with the same iOs-version (7.0.2) works.

I have tested the above page from both a https://x.y.domain.tld and a http://x.domain.tld with the same exception.

Other questions concerning "DOM Exception 18" seem to be about security settings when eg. testing on localhost but linking in remote content over https. But this is a simple html page that simply tries to access local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved. It was revealed that the client (the errant phone was a client phone) uses a company-wide security platform installed on their iPhones. That platform has a separate web browser that must be used to enable every Javascript feature. The end user with the phone didn't know this so he used Safari that somehow is crippled when this platform is active. So the solution was to use the right application for browsing.

The platform was http://www.mobileiron.com/ and the secure browser is called [Web@Work](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/products/webwork)

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that if cookies are blocked, the DOM Exception 18 error shows up when setting localStorage. I was able to reproduce the error (not sure if I reproduced the issue, per se) on a simulator iPhone 5 (w/ iOS7) by going to the Settings, then for Safari, "Block Cookies" always. Don't know if that's how your iPhone 5 is configured though...

Comment: See my answer, the problem was solved. But we did try to toggle every setting (thankfully not that many) in Safari, trying every combination. I should have added that to my question.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen that you can't change data in local storage within the first couple of seconds. Set a timer for 5000 milliseconds, and then run the setItem-function to see what happens.

Comment: Expand on your answer, this is only worth a comment.

Comment: Reputation not over 50. Can't comment on answers

Comment: See my answer the problem was solved. But from the start it was clear that this wasn't the problem since one of the first tests was a page that accessed the localstorage on a button click, with the same result whenever the button was clicked, should have added that to the question.

Comment: This is unequivocally false.